# File Associations in a Windows Store App, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I followed the msdn tutorial and another tutorial, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  In app.xaml.cs, I have the code

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
        }

        var p = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        p.FileEvent = args;
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs I have the code

```
private FileActivatedEventArgs _fileEventArgs = null; 
    public FileActivatedEventArgs FileEvent
    {
        get { return _fileEventArgs; }
        set { _fileEventArgs = value; }
    }
```

and

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the args
        if (FileEvent != null && FileEvent.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            titleText.Text = FileEvent.Files[0].Path.ToString();
        }
    }
```

which is called in the MainPage constructor after this.InitializeComponent().
I'm not sure how to debug it.  When I double click on an mp3 file that is associated with the app, the app opens but does not start, and the file has the waiting pointer icon until I close the app, then I receive an error that says The App didn't start in the required time. If the app is already open when I click on the file, nothing happens, and when I close the app it says The Remote procedure call failed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had put the entry point to MainPage.xaml, but changing it to App.xaml.cs fixed it so it actually called OnFileActivated().  I also changed the OnFileActivated code to

```
    protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
        var p = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        if (p != null) p.FileEvent = args;
        p.MainPage_Loaded(null, null);
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

calling the public method p.MainPage_Loaded() in MainPage.xaml.cs from App.xaml.css was the final touch that allowed me to use the method without creating a new frame if the app was already open.